# ImageIO Exception

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am getting the following error:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
Resource not found: C:\icon.gif
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
at connector.SystemTrayCreator.createImage(SystemTrayCreator.java:98)
at connector.SystemTrayCreator.create(SystemTrayCreator.java:36)
at connector.Start.main(Start.java:14)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: creating TrayIcon with     null Image
at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(TrayIcon.java:168)
at connector.SystemTrayCreator.create(SystemTrayCreator.java:36)
at connector.Start.main(Start.java:14)
Java Result: 1
```

Out of the following code:

```
final TrayIcon trayIcon = 
            new TrayIcon(createImage("C:\\icon.gif", "Tray icon"));
```

with

```
protected static Image createImage(String path, String description) {
    Image image = null;

    try {
        File f = new File(path);
        image = ImageIO.read(f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (image == null) {
        Debugger.showMessage("Resource not found: " + path);
        return null;
    } else {
        return (new ImageIcon(image, description)).getImage();
    }
}
```

I am quite sure that the path is correct. Also, the names match.

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: according to the stack trace the `createImage()` method is returning null, and then the `TrayIcon` constructor has a problem with this. You are sure the file is at that location?

Comment: It's returning `null` because its try-block failed to load the image. We need to explain that failure. Its stacktrace is the first one in the output dump.

Comment: Yes, I am sure the file is at that location. Also I don't think you need more code, I only use the path in that method. @Marko Topolnik you can see the output I get, but that isn't helping me any further either...

Comment: think i'm having the same problem. did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems fine. Two things currently occur to me as theoretically possible problems:

1. A file permission problem. Maybe place the file somewhere else than the drive root and check explicitly its permissions. You may call `canRead()` directly from your code -- that's what `ImageIO.read` does. It must return `true`.
2. There could be some whitespace at the end of your `path` argument. Use `trim()` to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: I placed the file into my own user directory, but it still gives the same error. Smart one about the trim(), though that wasn't the problem...

Comment: Work on making `canRead()` return `true`. I really can't see any issues with your code.

Comment: Neither did I =/ Thanks though.

Comment: Are you by any chance executing this code from an applet in a browser? That would explain a lot.

Comment: Nope, executing it local. Even tried to put it in the C:\ or C:\Users\username\Documents, it still can't be read. To make it even more strange, I'm actually able to read and write other files in exact the same way. This one just won't read.